# Excel - Find text values from a range in different columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with 5 columns which contain several words ("tags") but they have been pasted into those columns incorrectly (currently there is no way to fix this).

[image: Image with the Table]

There are 5 **groups of tags** and what I need to do is to create 5 new columns (for each group of tags) and create a formula which could look in each column and see which tag is contained in those columns/range. As in this example:

[image: Table with new columns]

The group of tags are:

[image: Tags Groups]

How can I do this? I have been trying with the LOOKUP formulas and COUNTIF but I have not been able to do it... I think it is because they only allow you to look up for one value at the time (and not several values from a range (a group of tags)).

Thanks!

Markdown:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 | Group #1 | Group #2 | Group #3 | Group #4 | Group #5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| my-product | Company University | non billable | Others | product | product | Others | my-product | Company University | non billable |
| content | Partner Software KHG | non billable | partner-product | service | service | content | partner-product | Partner Software | non billable |
| app-modernization | non billable | partner-product | Pega | service |  |  |  |  |  |
| capture | Partner Caption | non billable | partner-product | service |  |  |  |  |  |
| my-product | Company University | non billable | Others | product |  |  |  |  |  |
| my-product | Company University | non billable | Others | product |  |  |  |  |  |
| capture | my-product | non billable | product | PRODCAPTURE |  |  |  |  |  |
| app-modernization | non billable | partner-product | SF | service |  |  |  |  |  |
| content | Partner Others | non billable | partner-product | service |  |  |  |  |  |
| my-product | Company University | non billable | Others | product |  |  |  |  |  |
| my-product | non billable | product | PRODSUITE | robotic-automation |  |  |  |  |  |
| app-modernization | Hardware | non billable | product | solution |  |  |  |  |  |
| capture | my-product | non billable | product | PRODCAPTURE |  |  |  |  |  |
| capture | my-product | non billable | product | PRODCAPTURE |  |  |  |  |  |
| my-product | non billable | Others | product | PRODSUITE |  |  |  |  |  |
| app-modernization | Customer Communications Management (CCM) | non billable | product | solution |  |  |  |  |  |
| my-product | Company University | non billable | Others | product |  |  |  |  |  |
| my-product | Company University | non billable | Others | product |  |  |  |  |  |
| app-modernization | general | non billable | PRODBRE | service |  |  |  |  |  |
| content | Partner Software KHG | non billable | partner-product | service |  |  |  |  |  |
| my-product | non billable | Others | product | PRODSUITE |  |  |  |  |  |
| All | my-product | non billable | product | PRODSUITE |  |  |  |  |  |
| capture | my-product | non billable | product | PRODCAPTURE |  |  |  |  |  |
| capture | my-product | non billable | product | PRODCAPTURE |  |  |  |  |  |
| content | my-product | non billable | product | PRODCASEMAG |  |  |  |  |  |

GROUPS OF TAGS

| Group #1 |  | Group #2 |  | Group #3 |  | Group #4 |  | Group #5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| product |  | app-modernization |  | my-product |  | advantice |  | billable |
| service |  | capture |  | general |  | Product UYF |  | non billable |
|  |  | content |  | partner add-on product |  | Cosmos Software |  |  |
|  |  | Others |  | partner-product |  | UI Development |  |  |
|  |  | robotic-automation |  | solution |  | Customer Custom Application |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | Hardware |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | Other Services |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  | HGMD |  |  |

Group 4 is longer, but I won't paste it all here...

Comment: Hi, I converted the tables to markdown. I hope it helps (first time posting here)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Office 365 you could use:
`=FILTER(Table1[Group '#1],COUNTIF($A1:$E1,Table1[Group '#1]))`

For ROW 1, Group #1. I noticed you already have the groups setup as tables. You may need to adjust the table name. For Group #2 change the table in the formula, etc.

Comment: The proposed formula worked fine! Thanks so much!